# C++ Win32 PostQuitMessage(0) not working? CPU @ 100%

Tags: winapi

OK so I have my main window procedure (simplified):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            if(!loadFiles())
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        }
        break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return 0;
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

loadFiles() is a function to read some text files. If the files are missing, it posts an error message and then returns false. I handle this by sending the WM_CLOSE message, which sends WM_DESTROY? The program calls PostQuitMessage(0) and.. nothing. The process is still sitting in background, now using 100% CPU on core 1. Here is my message loop :

```
MSG Msg;
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
return Msg.wParam;
```

Very simple, I've looked around and seen people using all kinds of different loops, most with PeekMessage() function.. its worth noting I have several child windows containing different controls, I show and hide them when the user selects different tabs, but I don't think it matters because PostQuitMessage(0) is supposed to post WM_QUIT to the message queue, which destroys the child windows aswell right? Any help? Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown so it has to be a problem with code you have not shown yet. Use a debugger to find out where your code is getting stuck.

Comment: It is pointless to put `return 0;` under your `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_CASE` case, because you have already declared `break` under them, which will eventually `return 0` after breaking. I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe it has something to do with your other codes?

Comment: Try sending `WM_CLOSE` using `PostMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `WM_CREATE` is sent during `CreateWindow`. So you are destroying the window right during creation. I am not sure that this is supposed to work. Also, why so complicated? The documentation says

> If an application processes this message, it should return zero to
>   continue creation of the window. *If the application returns –1, the
>   window is destroyed and the CreateWindowEx or CreateWindow function
>   returns a NULL handle.*

So just return -1 in case `loadFiles()` fails and handle `CreateWindow` returning `NULL` accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, instead of trying to send a destroy message during creation, returning -1 will fail to create the window in the first place.. thank you, it worked